# Подогнать текст под размер кнопки

Tags: android, android-textview, android-button

В моей программе я обширно использую `weight` компонентов, подгоняя текст кнопок с помощью небольшой функции использующей `paint.getTextBounds`. Моя функция ищет размер текста который влезет в границы кнопки. В эту функцию я передаю контейнер и текст, где происходят замеры примерно так:

```
 paint.setTypeface(typeface);
 paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);
 int cWidth  = container.getMinimumWidth();
 int cHeight = container.getMinimumHeight();
 int tWidth = textRect.width();
 int tHeight = textRect.height();
 if ((tWidth>cWidth)||(tHeight>cHeight)){
  //текст не влез
 } else { 
  //текст влез
 }
```

На эмуляторе с небольшими размерами экрана у меня несколько кнопок получили

```
mMinHeight = 168
mMeasuredHeight = 102
```

соответственно размер текста подобран слишком большой для компонента. Но на момент создания кнопки `mMesauredHeight` еще не существует, точнее равен 0. Поэтому я использовал `getMinimumHeight`. Подход через `MinHeight` явно не работает для маленьких экранов. Смотрю в сторону onMeasure и onLayout.

Собственно можно ли как то еще узнать размеры компонентов в момент их создания? Может существует другой простой способ подогнать текст под размер вьюшки?

Answer (score 1):

Да, правильно смотрите. Ещё можно добавить метод `onSizeChanged()` к этой же категории. Только учтите, что в зависимости от сложности лэйоута эти методы могут вызываться по несколько раз, ну и окончательные размеры будут уже при последнем вызове.